# How to access data while using Factory provider in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-providers, angular-factory

when i have a provider like this

```
  { provide: SaModelService, useValue: 'foo@yahoo.com' }
```

i am able to get the value by just using like this in the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: SaModelService, useValue: 'foo@yahoo.com' }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private model: SaModelService) {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.model);
  }

}
```

where the service looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class SaModelService {


    }
```

now, how can i get the value while using the factory provider, ie

```
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => function () { return 'foo@yahoo.com' },
      multi: true
    }
```

> now i have given this example just to simplify the scenerio but
>   instead of just passing the string, i want to call some services inside
>   the factory

my question is, is there any access to the variable, if not then how will i be getting the value which i would be using inside my component